# Running app processes indefinitely in the background

Tags: ios, swift3, background

I want to make a Test app that continuously increases an int by one after it is first opened and doesn’t stop if it is closed in the background or completely closed (when you double tap the home button and swipe up on an apps screen on an iphone, I don’t know what it’s called).

I know that certain apps can run even though the user is currently not looking at it, but how do i get an app to run indefinitely in the background?

What I am looking for is similar to the way the game Tiny Towers (you build a tower and it earns money over time) keeps profits while it is offscreen or completely closed.

Comment: That's not the way to do that. Something like that should do nothing in the background. When the app comes back to the front, you work out how long it has been and, in your case, work out what the correct value for the int should be now.

Comment: If you aren't going to release it on the app store then you can use the audio background mode and play "silence" to keep your app running, but apps like Tiny Tower actually just store the time that it enters the background and then calculates the elapsed time when it enters the foreground in order to calculate the earned money.  This uses much less energy than running in the background continually

Comment: So if I were to do something like the tiny towers method, would a constantly updating timer work?

Comment: Would the appDidEnterBackground function be where I would do all of these calculations?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide a specification for the `info.plist` file like the **UIBackgroundModes** and as for completely terminating the app, you could set up a broadcast receiver.